# Change fontsize in TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I had my documentclass set at 10pt and I import my TikZ figures just with `\input`. Everything was working fine but now I want to have 11pt in the document and all my nodes are bigger because the fonts are now bigger and everything is distorted.

So, how can I set the fontclass (or whatever name it has) in TikZ to 10pt so the normalfont in the figures is 10pt as I had designed everything with in mind instead of 11pt that would be the actual document?

Answer (score 19):

If you do not change the font size within your pictures, it is fairly simple and you could just try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  font={\fontsize{10pt}{12}\selectfont}}
\begin{document}
  This is some text.

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {This is a node.};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  This is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: size switch]

Obviously, if you use commands like `\small` etc. within pictures, things are more complicated.

Comment: Wouldn't `\tikzset{font=\small}` work as well?

Comment: @PierPaolo Yes. But I would specify it explicitly so that if I later change the global setting, the figure will still come out correctly. (E.g. if I later decide to go back to `10pt` or if I decide on `12pt`.) Since the diagram requires a specific size, it makes more sense to use an absolute specification than one dependent on the document default setting. That is, the advantage of `\small` is that it will automatically adjust if you change the global size. But that is precisely what is *not* wanted in this case.

Comment: @cfr I have a document with 12pt and would like to have the all tikz graphics at 10pt. And I still want to use `\small` to get the respective 10pt `\small` variant in the picture. How can I get that?

Comment: @n4pK Why would you want to do that? I mean you could, if you really wanted to change the meaning of `\small` in every `tikzpicture`, but why not just use a different command in these cases?

Comment: @n4pK I would define a new macro to give the size you want and then `\let\standardsmall\small\let\small\newsizemacro` at the start of the environment, where the font is set to 10pt. But I'd only do this if, like the OP, your code is already written and you need a 'quick fix'. Otherwise, better to use the `\newsizemacro` directly.

Comment: @cfr My intention is, the following: I realized, that in many books the font in the graphics is set in sans serif. Additionally, often the font is slightly smaller than the main body font. (IMHO it separates the graphic more from the text body.) Further, some of my (already existing) graphics are quite large and latex is having trouble with the filling of some pages.

Comment: @n4pK I would try to stick to sizes standard for your 12pt document if you can.Best would be not to reuse the standard macros, which will make your code more confusing, but you can do this, if you really need to, as explained above.

Comment: The font=\small crashed in my minimal document; better use the fontsize. just FYI