# change fontsize within tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, scrreprt

i made some tikzpicture and tested them outside of the main document cause then there's less compiling duration.

However i alway used `\documentclass{article}`.

I set the fonts with  `\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,  font = {\sf \myfont}, thick]`.

For `\myfont` i used `\newcommand{\myfont}{\footnotesize}`.

After creating the tikzpicture i wanted to add the `tikzpicture` with `\input{mytikzpicture.tex}` in to my main document.

But somehow the change of the fontsize i set with `\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,  font = {\sf \myfont}, thick]` has no effect now.

In my main document i set the font size using this code:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    oneside,
    fleqn,
    listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,
    headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot,
    hyphens,
]{scrreprt}
```

What i already tried:

- `\tikzset{font={\fontsize{9pt}{12}\selectfont}}`
  I wanted  to use this to decrease the font size in a tikzpicture only. I got this solution from searching the internet ([Change fontsize in TikZ figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226971/change-fontsize-in-tikz-figure)). Unfortunately it had no effect on the fontsize in the tikzpicture at all.
- changing the fontsize using kind of scoping (also no effect): found at
  [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45021/latex-does-not-adjust-font-size)

  ```
  {\footnotesize % change the font size
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,  font = {\sf \myfont}, thick]
     ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
  } % end of scope of \footnotesize macro
  ```

What's the reason it doesn't work and what can i change?
If i didn't provide all necessary information to solve the problem feel free to tell me.

edit1:

here a minimum example of my problem.
the tex file i use for developing my tikzpictures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\footnotesize}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,
rounded corners]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,  font = {\myfont}, thick]
    % Hilfslinien
    \draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
    \node[block, align=center] (isolation) {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

minimum example if i put my developed stuff into the main document:

```
\documentclass[
pdftex,
a4paper,
11pt,
oneside,
fleqn,
listof=totoc,
headlines=2.1,
headsepline,
numbers=noenddot,
hyphens,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}




\newcommand{\myfont}{\footnotesize}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,
rounded corners]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,  font = {\myfont}, thick]
    % Hilfslinien
    \draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);


    \node[block, align=center] (isolation) {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Outputs:
[image]
The left side shows the output of my 'devolopment' file. The right is the output of the main document.

As you can see if i put it into the main document the fonts are slightly bigger. This is enough to distort all my tikzpictures.
Thank in advance

Comment: Please post a compilable document, not disrupted pieces of code

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done. see the edit. best regards

Comment: in main document you use 11pt font size, but in file, in which you develop your picture, you use default font size, which is 10 pt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default font size for KOMA-Script classes is `11pt`, but for standard classes it is `10pt`.

Maybe you can change the font size for all tikzpictures to `10pt` using

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\tikzpicture{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt% 11pt is default for KOMA-Script classes
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw,rounded corners}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\tikzpicture{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,font = {\myfont}, thick]
% help lines
\draw[help lines,lightgray!50] (-5,-5) grid[step=2mm] (5,5);
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\node[block] (isolation) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Example with `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}% default font size is 10pt
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\sffamily\footnotesize}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw,rounded corners}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,font = {\myfont}, thick]
% help lines
\draw[help lines,lightgray!50] (-5,-5) grid[step=2mm] (5,5);
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\node[block] (isolation) {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:[image]

Comment: Thank you. I seems to work in the minimum examples. Do i need to to set `\xpretocmd\tikzpicture{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}}{}{\PatchFailed}`in front of every tikzpicture or only once in a header-file, where i include all my usepackages?

Comment: You have to set it only once in header. It affects all `tikzpicture` environments.